# Is it possible to make a shared folder in YouTube

Tags: youtube

Is it possible to make a shared folder in a YouTube account and share all videos in that folder with a pre-selected person or group of people?

I've got 20 videos id like to be private, but shared with a specific group of people. I don't want to have to manually share it with each person, so would rather drop them into a folder which is pre-shared like you can with Google Drive. Is that possible with YouTube?

Answer (score 4):

Until recently(-ish), you could share private videos with Google+ circles, however, due to the widely requested Google+ unintegration, this no longer is possible.

What you can do however is enter multiple email addresses separated with commas, ie: `matt@example.com, titanic@example.com, bo@example.com` and save that list somewhere so you can copypaste it whenever necessary.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is ive got literally 100s of videos (CCTV events) that i need to share with relevant people, but not leave open on the internet. Even having a list i can copy and paste will take ages, do you know if its possible to put them all in a playlist and share the playlist with them ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can automate that procedure using the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3).